# Where is $GEM_PATH usually set?

Tags: bash, rubygems, rvm

Where is $GEM_PATH set?

It clearly is being set as this shows:

```
echo $GEM_PATH
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318:/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global
```

but it's not where I'd expect, e.g.

```
[app (master)]$ grep GEM_PATH ~/.bash_profile
[app (master)]$ grep GEM_PATH ~/.bashrc
[app (master)]$
```

EDIT

Neither is it here:

```
vim config/environment.rb 

# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Accounts::Application.initialize!
```

Comment: how about `grep "GEM_PATH" /etc/profile`?

Comment: nope - not there either. Or, fwiw, /etc/bashrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default ruby is loaded when you `source /path/to/rvm/scripts/rvm`, and setting default ruby amount other sets `GEM_HOME`, `GEM_PATH` and `PATH`

Answer (score 1):

**(Edited)** A few other places to check for `GEM_PATH`:

- `config/environment.rb`
- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/profile.d`
- `/etc/bashrc`

See also: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html